# Updating row in datatable and saving to database

Tags: powershell, datatable, sqldataadapter

I have to reset a column called "certRenewal" in a table on MS SQL Server. I'm attempting this in Powershell. Basically, the idea I'm thinking is to get the entire table in a DataTable object and then foreach through all Rows and find where "certRenewal" is $true (its a bit column). And change it to $false. Here is the code. The code doesn't give me any error but it also doesn't update the table in SQL Server.

```
param(
        [string]$SQLServerName="ServerName\InstanceName"
        ,[string]$SQLDatabaseName="MyDataBase"
        ,[string]$SQLTableName = "UserList"
        ,[string]$SQLQuery1="SELECT * FROM $SQLTableName"
    )
    
    # Create connection
    $sqlConn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $sqlConn.ConnectionString = “Server=$SQLServerName;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=$SQLDatabaseName”
    $sqlConn.Open()
    
    
    # Get all users
    $sqlCommand = $sqlConn.CreateCommand()
    $sqlCommand.CommandText = $SQLQuery1
    
    
    $dataAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $sqlCommand
    $dataTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
    $dataAdapter.Fill($dataTable) | Out-Null
    
    
    
    foreach($dataRow in $dataTable.Rows)
    {
        if($dataRow["certRenewal"] -eq $true)
        {
            $dataRow["certRenewal"] = $false
            $dataTable.AcceptChanges()
        }
    }
    
    
    $dataAdapter.Update($dataTable)
    $sqlConn.Close()
```

I know I could build and send an Update command as well and I don't need DataAdapter for that. But  I wanted to know if doing it through DataTable and through iterating all rows and updating the row and saving it DataTable, is it possible to do it this way?

Answer (score 1):

Can you do what you describe with DataTable - absolutely. But why, given your requirements it seems like massive overkill. Anyway...

Your question states `find where "certRenewal" is $true` - but your code says `if($dataRow["certRenewal"] -eq $false)` - im guessing thats a typo? I think your issue is on that line though, but its due to the datatype in SQL doesn't evaluate as your expecting with PowerShells `$true`/`$false`.

Drop some `Write-Host` lines to confirm the flow of execution like this:

```
        Write-Host $dataRow["certRenewal"]
        if($dataRow["certRenewal"] -eq $false)
        {
            Write-Host "certRenewal is false"            ​
           ​$dataRow["certRenewal"] = $true
           ​$dataTable.AcceptChanges()
       ​}else{
           ​Write-Host "certRenewal is true"
       ​}
```

Run the SQL command: `DESCRIBE $SQLTableName;` from POSH or inspect the table in Management Studio to find the exact datatype of `certRenewal`. (Or you could include in your foreach `$dataRow| ConvertTo-Json` to get a look at the data instead). It might be of type `bit`, or a `char(1)` - bit's are just numbers, chars need wrapping with quotes `'Y'`.

---

Sledge-hammer to crack a nut...

Using DataTable for such a simple operation is unnecessary and expensive - and your not getting much value for that expense.At a practical level as the number of rows increase the inefficiency of this approach will become a problem.

As a rule you should select as little data as you need, so `SELECT * FROM $SQLTableName` is not a good start (if your dealing with hundreds or thousands of rows this is probably OK but its a bad habit to get into and does not scale well). (below assumes `certRenewal` is a bit datatype, you need to adapt these examples to your tables schema).

A slight improvement would be `SELECT * FROM $SQLTableName WHERE certRenewal = 0` - so your only selecting the rows where certRenewal is false - but this is still pulling all the other columns that are never used...

A further improvement would be selecting just the column you intend to use: `SELECT certRenewal FROM $SQLTableName WHERE certRenewal = 0` - this reduces the total amount of data quite considerably from the original query. Your only fetching a single value for each row which your code is expecting.

Generally you want to avoid unnecessary round trips to the database, and send as little data back and forth as you can - its faster, its cheaper, its just a really good idea. So, `select *` statements aside - i would go with SQL `UPDATE` command.

`UPDATE` statements will update all rows that match the where clause, and set a field to the given value to each of them. This means minimal data is transmitted - just the number rows modified etc are returned, and all the work is done by the database server.

The following command will instruct SQL to find all rows where `certRenewal` is false, and set them to true. If you compare this query to your `select *` approach, even on low numbers of rows the speed difference should be visible. Bandwidth costs money, and data takes time to transit - always try and offload operations to SQL where you can, and if you have to fetch data, fetch as little as possible.

```
UPDATE $SQLTableName
SET certRenewal = 0
WHERE certRenewal = 1;
```

Also, i dont think you need `$dataTable.AcceptChanges()` - its just marking the rows as updated not actually doing anything useful, you just need to commit the changes after the loop as you have done

Comment: Hi @MisterSmith. Thanks for your response. Yes, the data type is bit (not bool, sorry my bad). And yes that condition is a typo. It should be to find where "certRenewal" is $true. The reason I wanted to do a Foreach loop is because I have to send an email notification to the user and other columns in that table contain user's email. Now I have not got to that step yet so my code doesnt reflect anything about email. But basically if certRenewal -eq true, then 1. send email user and 2. change certrenewal to $False. But using the approach it doesnt update the certRenewal column. :(

Comment: That makes sense. Edit your question and add your latest code and include the output of the Write-Host lines. If still reccomend changing your sql to something like `select ID,Name,Email from $SQLTableName where certRenewal = 1` (or whatever your fields are called - make sure you include a unique key "ID" in the above example for when you make your `UPDATE` call). I would expect changing `if($dataRow["certRenewal"] -eq $true)` to `if($dataRow["certRenewal"] -eq 1)` if that field is a bit should work. `$true`/`$false` are powershell constructs not SQL.

Comment: I have some new requirements. I will post my question again. This time I will put the table def and example data etc. Thanks for your patience with this question and your help.